# Should I use firebase facebook authentication?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am making an android app and a website linked to same online database. I want to add firebase facebook auth to the app, but for that I will have to use firebase hosting, which I read does not support dynamic website hosting. So is there any other way or should I not use firebase auth? I cannot google the problem so help pls.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase supports dynamic hosting, have a look
https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions